# Generating Radiobutton grid menu from an Array in Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, arrays, grid, tkinter

Edit: Sorry I can't answer my own post since I'm new but I figured it out: If you remove the line "tki.Button(master,..." (2nd to last code line), then the code runs perfectly fine. I guess the grid and the button don't work the way I put it.

sorry to bother but I'm having a little trouble figuring out what's off here. Basically I have an array that I want to loop through and set each of the values as a radiobutton IN A GRID. Later I'm going to loop through several arrays to generate a larger grid menu, but I can probably figure that out once I get this first loop working.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tki

master = tki.Tk()
frm = tki.Frame(master, bd = 16, relief = "sunken")
frm.grid()

tType = tki.StringVar()
tColumn = tki.IntVar()
tRow = tki.IntVar()
compType = ["iMac ", "Mac Mini ", "Mac Pro ", "Macbook ", "Macbook Air ", "Macbook Pro "]
tColumn.set(0)
tRow.set(0)

def radioCreate(typeArray):
    for t in typeArray:
        b = tki.Radiobutton(frm, text = t, variable = tType)
        b.config(indicatoron = 0, bd = 4, width = 16, value = t)
        b.grid(row = tRow.get(), column = tColumn.get())
        tRow.set((tRow.get() + 1))  #increment tRow for next run-through

def p():
    print tType.get()

radioCreate(compType)
tki.Button(master, command = p, text = "Display").pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Now remember, I'm trying to get this working in a grid, because I'm going to populate other columns with other data from different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is i. These two lines:

```
frm.grid()
...
tki.Button(...).pack()
```

While it's perfectly acceptable to use `pack` and `grid` in the same application, you can't use them on two widgets that share the same master.

Grid will potentially change the size of a widget or its master depending on its options. Pack will notice the change, and may itself try to resize one or more widgets and/or the master based on its options. Grid will notice the change, and may resize... Pack will notice the change and resize, ...